# How to use ExifTool in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, exif, exiftool

[ExifTool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool) is a free and open-source software program for reading, writing, and manipulating image, audio, video, and PDF metadata.

It has one problematic feature, after it finishes it stops and tells you to 'press RETURN' to continue which is a game breaker, because if you use it in some batch file that also performs other commands, all them gets delayed until user manually presses ENTER each time on his keyboard.

How to bypass that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [exiftool main page](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/):

"rename to "exiftool.exe" for command-line use."

Exiftool allows for command line options to be accessed through drag and drop if you put them in the name of the program.  In the default case, the `-k` option is in the name to keep the CMD window open so users and drag/drop and then read the output.

Comment: That worked. Any idea why it change rotation of the photo? They became upside down.

Comment: What is your command?  If you are doing something like removing metadata with `-all:all=` then you are removing the `orientation` tag. Most cameras (esp phones) keep track of the orientation of the phone and place this info in the `orientation` tag so that image viewing programs can display the image properly.  In order to keep the orientation, use something like `-all:all= -tagsfromfile @ -orientation /Target/FileOrDir`  Another option is to first use a program that can do a lossless rotation on your jpegs.  This is what I do and I use Irfanview with it's lossless rotation plugin. Works great